# Forum CIVI registration

Tags: registration

registration is currently disable on CIVI forum
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?action=register
Does anyone knows if it's temporary ?

Thank's

Comment: Such questions can be asked on https://chat.civicrm.org channels for an instant reply

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about status of a civicrm.org service that will go stale, rather than a question that will continue to be relevant to the community.